# How to install Snappy Ubuntu Core without a keyboard

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I bought a raspberry pi 3 to use as a server, and only after getting part way through the [Ubuntu Core installation instructions](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/) did I realise that I actually don't own a USB keyboard... (we're a laptop household) Oops.

I can boot the raspberry pi and see it on the network, and its SSH server is up and running, but obviously it doesn't know my username or SSH keys and so won't let me log in.

Is there some way to get it working by editing files on the SD card with my main laptop then SSHing in? Or do I actually need to go out and acquire a keyboard for this 60 seconds of use?

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated Answer

As of Ubuntu Snappy 16.04 , things have changes quite a lot. During the first boot you will need to have physical connection to Snappy. Best approach is via serial cable and `screen` ( see my old answer for details ) to configure it first, and then log in via ssh.

At first boot you will be able to configure wireless connection and register your Raspberry with Launchpad ( aka Single-Sign-On ) username. This means that you have to have your laptop's/desktop's `ssh` public key registered on Launchpad. So for this part what you need is this:

1. Have Launchpad ID created
2. Generate ssh keys with `ssh-keygen`
3. Copy your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to Launchpad.
4. Now connect to Raspberry ( via serial cable or keyboard + monitor approach)
5. Configure wireless, configure your admin account. At this point Raspberry will contact Launchpad and get your ssh public key. You will be told with which username and ip address you can ssh into Raspberry.For example for me it was `serg@192.168.0.84`, so I did `ssd serg@192.168.0.84`. Because Raspberry knows your ssh public key, first ssh login will not require password.

These steps are pretty much shorter version of [Ubuntu's official documentation](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/), but the steps explained exactly as I followed them. I did run into a bit of issue where I had this error from `ssh` during first log-in:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

This can be solved with simply running `ssh-add`.

---

#### Old answer ( relevant for pre-16.04 releases )

Let's assume your Raspberry Pi's ip address is `192.168.0.25`. If you're trying to just run

```
ssh 192.168.0.25
```

It will obviously assume you're trying to log in with the same username as what you use on your laptop/desktop. But what I see from your question is that you just installed Ubuntu Snappy onto the SD card and booting the Raspberry. This means you can ssh into it with default username and password, both are `ubuntu`:

```
ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.25
```

Thus, you don't really need USB keyboard for that. USB keyboard would be necessary only if you've connected Raspberry to a monitor and trying to log in same way as on desktop/laptop.

Another things you can do is acquire  USB serial cable and log into it via serial console using  `screen`. This is personally what I do if I don't need to do anything network-related on my Raspberry. The slight nuance is that you need to properly connect pins on raspberry and use only USB 2.0 port on laptop/desktop. Once connected, Raspberry will power up, and you can issue a command:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

where /dev/ttyUSB0 is device file represented by your Raspberry and 115200 is the baud-rate, or speed, of transmission between the two machines. Keep in mind that  ending number of the device file may be different ( but in my experience it usually starts out with 0).

Comment: certain this still works with the "new"  snappy-core 16?

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work for me:
```
ubuntu@192.168.1.221's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: @Felix OK, i suppose they indeed changed things around for 16.04. I downloaded an iso today myself but didn't get to test it yet. At least in 15.04 this way would work. You probably have to get keyboard, or better yet get the serial cable, like i explained in the second part of my answer. I'll olay around with 16.04 and let you know if i find anything, ok ?

Comment: @Felix I've tried 16.04. It is indeed different than old versions, and is quite more involved so yes, you really need keyboard or at least serial cable.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame that the answer seems to be "you can't". Looks like the console-conf script that runs in the console session does a bunch of things that can't easily be replicated by editing files by hand (e.g. setting up a user account). But I found a keyboard I could borrow, and have reached the next level of my adventure!

Answer (score 0):

Without a keyboard, you can simply use a serial connection over USB with a serial console cable like this https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview