# How to log into Snappy Core?

Tags: virtualbox, ssh, password, ubuntu-core

Okay, so I downloaded the `i386` image for Ubuntu Snappy Core, unpack it, convert it to a VDI and attach it to VirtualBox VM. All good. I generate my SSH keys and add them to my Ubuntu One account. I boot the VM, go through the set up process, and enter my Ubuntu One email address. I get a message that tells me to log in, I use `ssh geoffreys@192.168.1.16`. I try to do that, but then I have a problem. I can't log in because I don't know the password. I try my Ubuntu One password, no luck. The password used to generate the SSH keyfiles, still no. I try no password. Also negatory. The KVM builds (I'm using one) don't have the default `ubuntu` user account, so I can't use that. I also can't go into the root account.I'm out of options. I've ran through the setup process twice, so I know it's not an error during setup. Any ideas, anyone? Any help would me much appreciated.

Edit: I tried booting into single-user mode, but the `/` directory is `ro`, so I can't use `passwd` to change the root password. Looking at the boot process and grub parameters, it seems that the root directory is mounted as a loopv evice at boot.

Comment: Did you generate any `.pem` files during the setup process? If so, you need to specify them with the `-i yourkeyfile.pem` option...

Comment: I don't know and I don't think so. I can't even log in so I have no idea what is on the VM's filesystem. If you mean in the host's `~/.ssh`, then no. I just checked. Als0, specify them when and where?

Comment: Ubuntu Snappy 16.04 has very tight security policy. You indeed need to generate ssh key and have Launchpad account. See the related question: http://askubuntu.com/a/851813/295286

Comment: Yes, I did create a Ubuntu One account and imported my host's SSH keys as described [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#snappy-local).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am feeling very stupid. It seems that the SSH keys under `~/.ssh` were somehow named differently, so I corrected the names and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/) to create a ssh key and upload to your Ubuntu account. While taking ownership of the device with the Ubuntu One email address (during first boot), your account name will be used to setup a new user with your ssh key as your login credential.

Comment: I followed the instructions [found here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#snappy-local) and did just that _before_ I even booted Snappy Core for the first time. I already did have a Ubuntu One account and did upload the host's SSH keys before I booted and configured my Snappy VM.

Comment: @GeoffreyS, can you try with `ssh -i <path-to-ssh-private-key-for-the-ubuntu-one-account> <ubuntu-one-username>@<localhost/ip>`